# Component is trying to load data before useEffect and useDispatch in react/nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

```
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getArticles())
  }, [dispatch])

{blog.articles.map((item) => {
  return <div>{item.name}</div>
})}
```

How do I wait for `getArticles()` before loading the ui?

Comment: You should load the data using `getServerSideProps`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to add a simple if statement at the beginning of the component:

```
if (!blog.articles || blog.articles.length == 0) 
   return <div>Loading...</div>;
```

This line of code checks if the `blog.articles` array is empty or undefined, and if so, it returns a simple loading indicator.

However, this approach has a limitation: it only checks if the `blog.articles` variable exists, but an empty array does not necessarily mean that the data is still loading.

You can add a loading state variable to the component, like so:

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
```

And then update this state in the useEffect using a Promise to wait for the dispatch function to finish executing:

```
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(getArticles())
    .then(() => {
      setIsLoading(false);
    });
}, [dispatch]);
```

Of course You can customize the loading indicator to make it more visually appealing, such as using a spinner or a skeleton loading animation.